# Copy data after specific text in a cell of a worksheet to another worksheet Makes Errors for the first sheet, Others are excellent

Tags: string, select, copy, record, summary

This MACRO makes error in copying the data from the first worksheet. It copies records to one row below in D column than the desired row and it repeats the last cell in column C in destination sheet. After this error, it works pretty well for all the other remaining worksheets. When I run it for only one worksheet manually, with F8 key, it works well. Can somebody help me to sort it out please?

```
     Sub My_Approach()

     Dim MAXT As String, fMaxT As String, MsTring As String
     Dim WBk1 As Workbook, WbK2 As Workbook
     Dim wSh4 As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
     Dim i As Long, lrow1 As Long, LroW2 As Long, lROw3 As Long, LrOw4 As Long
     Dim Mrng1 As Range, searchrange As Range, M As Range, f As Range, FoundRange1 As Range, 
     fOUNDranGE2 As Range, searcHRange1 As Range, fOUNDranGE3 As Range, mYtOTAL As Range
     Dim colFind As Collection, t As ListObjects
     MAXT = "FROM:"
     fMaxT = "TO:"
     MsTring = "MyNUMBER"
     Set WBk1 = ActiveWorkbook

     With WBk1
        If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
           For Each sh In WBk1.Worksheets
              sh.Select False
           Next
        End If
      End With

      Set WbK2 = Workbooks("TempBook.xlsx")
      Set wSh4 = WbK2.Sheets("RetrivedData")
       wSh4.Tab.Color = vbBlue
    

                  For Each sh In WBk1.Sheets
                    If sh.Name Like "20*" Then

                        sh.Select
                    With sh
                     .Cells.UnMerge
                     .rows("1:13").Interior.Color = vbRed
                     .rows("1:13").Delete
                    
                   End With

                    With sh
                       lrow1 = sh.Range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                    End With

                   Set searchrange = sh.Range("A1:A" & lrow1)

                   Set FoundRange1 = searchrange.Find(MAXT, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, False)
                    LroW2 = FoundRange1.row


                    Set fOUNDranGE2 = searchrange.Find(fMaxT, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, False)
                       lROw3 = fOUNDranGE2.row

                  Set Mrng1 = sh.Range("A1:L" & lROw3)

                  With wSh4
                   LrOw4 = wSh4.Range("C" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
                      Mrng1.Copy
                    wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4).Offset(1, -2).Formula = WBk1.Name
                    wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4).Offset(1, -1).Formula = sh.Name
                     Application.CutCopyMode = False
                   
                     LrOw4 = wSh4.Range("C" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

                  Set searcHRange1 = wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4)
                  Set fOUNDranGE3 = searcHRange1.Find(fMaxT, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, False)

                  If fOUNDranGE3.Value = "TO:" Then
                  Set mYtOTAL = fOUNDranGE3.Offset(0, 4)
                  mYtOTAL.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                  End If
                 End With

                 Set M = sh.Range(sh.Cells(fOUNDranGE2.Offset(0, 0).row, fOUNDranGE2.Offset(0, 0).Column), sh.Cells(lrow1, 1))
                 Set colFind = FindAll(M, MsTring)

                 For Each f In colFind
                         If f.Value = "MyNUMBER" Then

                      With wSh4
                          LrOw4 = wSh4.Range("C" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

                         wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4).Offset(1, 0).Value = f.Offset(2, 0).Value
                           wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4).Offset(1, 1).Value = f.Offset(4, 2).Value
                          wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4).Offset(1, 2).Value = f.Offset(2, 7).Value
                         wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4).Offset(1, 3).Value = f.Offset(2, 8).Value

                 If f.Offset(2, 8).Value = "SQ FT" Then
                         wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4).Offset(1, 4).Value = f.Offset(2, 7).Value / 43560
                 Else
                         wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4).Offset(1, 4).Value = f.Offset(2, 7).Value
                End If
                    wSh4.Range("C" & LrOw4).Offset(1, 5).Value = f.Offset(6, 10).Value
               End With
                End If
                Next f

             End If

             With wSh4
                      LrOw4 = wSh4.Range("C" & .rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
             End With

             wSh4.Range("C1:C" & LrOw4).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    
              mYtOTAL.Offset(0, -1).Formula = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wSh4.Range(wSh4.Cells(mYtOTAL.Offset(1, -4).row, mYtOTAL.Offset(1, -4).Column), wSh4.Cells(LrOw4, 3)))
              mYtOTAL.Offset(0, 1).Formula = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wSh4.Range(wSh4.Cells(mYtOTAL.Offset(1, 1).row, mYtOTAL.Offset(1, 1).Column), wSh4.Cells(LrOw4, 7)))
              mYtOTAL.Formula = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wSh4.Range(wSh4.Cells(mYtOTAL.Offset(1, 0).row, 
              mYtOTAL.Offset(1, 0).Column), wSh4.Cells(LrOw4, 6)))
              mYtOTAL.Offset(0, 1).Formula = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wSh4.Range(wSh4.Cells(mYtOTAL.Offset(1, 1).row, mYtOTAL.Offset(1, 1).Column), wSh4.Cells(LrOw4, 7)))


                Next sh

              WbK2.Save

                End Sub
```